# Transparent tabbar and actionbar using angular nativescript for android and ios

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to make the tab bar transparent and actionbar transparent over a swipelayout or page. The action or tab bar must sit on top of the page like in two layers

I have tried using css to make transparent but its doesnt become transparent over the page.

```
<ActionBar title="Name" backgroundColor="#00000000"></ActionBar>

<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom" selectedTabTextColor="white">
   <page-router-outlet
      *tabItem="{iconSource: getIconSource('test')}"
       name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{iconSource: getIconSource('test2')}"
        name="locationTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{iconSource: getIconSource('test3')}"
        name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>
</TabView>
```

transparent actionbar over the page

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r15in.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Style page / root layout with a background image or color of your choice

```
.page {
       background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/12/10/13/background-2633962__340.jpg);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
    }
```

**Android**

- Set `ActionBar`'s `backgroundColor` to `transparent`
- Upon `loaded` event adjust `Page` elements unit system

  ```
  onLoaded(event: EventData) {
      const layout = <GridLayout>event.object,
         page = layout.page;

      if (page.android) {
         page.android.removeRowAt(0);
      }
  }
  ```
- Adjust padding of root layout so the content will not overlap with ActionBar

**iOS**

Adjust `ActionBar` attributes upon `loaded` event

```
onActionBarLoaded(event: EventData) {
    const actionBar = <ActionBar>event.object;
    if (actionBar.ios) {
        (<any>actionBar).updateFlatness = function (navBar) {
            actionBar.ios.setBackgroundImageForBarMetrics(UIImage.new(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            actionBar.ios.translucent = true;
        };
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0rZCki) (Compatibility verified against v5.x)