# How to place content under ActionBar in NativeScript?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, uinavigationbar, nativescript

I have a transparent `ActionBar` and I would like to have content displayed underneath it. How can I achieve that in NativeScript?

---

<s>I have tried to set a `AbsoluteLayout` as the root layout of the page:</s>

```
<$Page
    ref={this.pageRef}
    iosOverflowSafeArea={true}
    backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar={true}
>
    <$AbsoluteLayout>
        <MyLayout />
        <AppBar ref={this.appBarRef}/>
    </$AbsoluteLayout>

</$Page>
```

In an attempt to make the ActionBar (AppBar) appear on top of my layout. But doing so makes the ActionBar disappear.

**Edit:** I did not know until recently that the tsx/jsx ÀctionBar implementation in react-nativescript sets the `actionBar` property of the page. When it is being set as a child of the page.

I have also tried to make some changes natively in iOS with no succees.

---

How can I have content displayed underneath `ActionBar`?

---

**On iOS** I have partially succeeded. Setting `iOSOverflowSafeArea=true` onto the component:

[image]

[image]

The layout (in orange) was underneath ActionBar all along. Something very strange though is that setting `height=0` on the button makes it assume the height of the `ActionBar`. So `height=1` is ActionBar's height plus 1.

---

**On Android** I found the following which supposedly would have made it work:

```
const activity = frame.android.activity as androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
activity.supportRequestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

... called after the onLoadedEvent`

> System.err: Error: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Window feature must be requested before adding content
>   System.err:     androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.throwFeatureRequestIfSubDecorInstalled(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java

**The only way seemed to be to edit the actionBar style declaration in res/values/styles.xml and res/values-v21/styles.xml.**.

Notice that those values already are set in the apptheme. The standard setup of the xml on android from a NativeScript vanilla ts project is the following...

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- theme to use FOR launch screen-->
    <style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>  
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>

    <style name="LaunchScreenTheme" parent="LaunchScreenThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme to use AFTER launch screen is loaded-->
    <style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    </style>

    <!-- theme for action-bar -->
    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>

    </style>

    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase">
    </style>
</resources>
```

values-v21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Application theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerDatePicker</item>
        <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerTimePicker</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Default style for DatePicker - in spinner mode -->
    <style name="SpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Default style for TimePicker - in spinner mode -->
    <style name="SpinnerTimePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
        <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NativeScriptToolbarStyle" parent="NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase">
        <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

It can also be noted that `NativeScript` seem to use special built layouts on the android side like [ContentLayout](https://github.com/NativeScript/tns-core-modules-widgets/blob/master/android/widgets/src/main/java/org/nativescript/widgets/ContentLayout.java) - but I am not sure to what extent this is the case.

Comment: Refer the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483982/1060423), If you just ignore `paddingTop` in the template, it should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @Manoj What is `(<any>actionBar).updateFlatness` in that sample?

Comment: Reming paddingTop did not help in the sample. I want the label in that sample to display through ActionBar/underneath it.

Comment: Let me know which platform specifically you are talking about, also please submit your update Playground.

Comment: I tested on iOS. I simply commented away the paddingTop: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=P343in

Comment: If you content is large enough and if you have ScrollView, then you will see the content scroll behind ActionBar. If you want the content to be behind ActionBar from start, use translateX.

Comment: @Manoj yes translate worked. But it would be tricky to use that approach since screen sizes and actiobars are different in height etc.

Comment: If I would make a custom actionBar view - using the actionBar css theme with it. How will page transition work. Backarrow and swipe to go back on iOS. Would it be difficult to get that working?